# populating ChoiceType with array of constants

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

What is the best way to populate a Symfony form choiceType with an array of constants defined in the underlying entity and add create an assert based on the same constants. 
The option names should be stored in the DB.

I am using Symfony 2.8and this is what I have done. It works well, but I think there must be an easier way with all the new form features.

Thanks, Hannes

Entity

```php
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    const OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_HIGHER_DEGREE = 'Schülerin/Schüler an Gymnasium';
    const OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_LOWER_DEGREE = 'Schülerin/Schüler an Haupt-/Real- und anderen Schulen';
    const OCCUPATION_WORK_TRAINING = 'Berufsausbildung';
    const OCCUPATION_UNIVERSITY = 'Studium an einer Hochschule';
    const OCCUPATION_WORK_FULLTIME = 'Vollzeiterwerbstätigkeit';
    const OCCUPATION_WORK_PARTTIME = 'Teilzeiterwerbstätigkeit';
    const OCCUPATION_NATIONAL_SERVICE = 'Wehrdienst/Zivildienst/FSJ/FÖJ';
    const OCCUPATION_UNEMPLOYED = 'keine Beschäftigung';
    const OCCUPATION_OTHERS = 'sonstiges';

...
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Pflichtfeld.")
     * @Assert\Choice(
     *      choices = {
     *          User::OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_HIGHER_DEGREE,
     *          User::OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_LOWER_DEGREE,
     *          User::OCCUPATION_WORK_TRAINING,
     *          User::OCCUPATION_UNIVERSITY,
     *          User::OCCUPATION_WORK_FULLTIME,
     *          User::OCCUPATION_WORK_PARTTIME,
     *          User::OCCUPATION_NATIONAL_SERVICE,
     *          User::OCCUPATION_UNEMPLOYED,
     *          User::OCCUPATION_OTHERS,
     *      },
     *      message = "Bitte wähle einen Eintrag aus der Liste."
     * )
     */
    private $occupation;

...
}
```

FormType

```html
class UserRegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Occupation
        $builder->add('occupation', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Beschäftigung*',
                'placeholder' => 'Bitte wählen',
                'choices' => array(
                    User::OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_HIGHER_DEGREE => User::OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_HIGHER_DEGREE,
                    User::OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_LOWER_DEGREE => User::OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_LOWER_DEGREE,
                    User::OCCUPATION_WORK_TRAINING => User::OCCUPATION_WORK_TRAINING,
                    User::OCCUPATION_UNIVERSITY => User::OCCUPATION_UNIVERSITY,
                    User::OCCUPATION_WORK_FULLTIME => User::OCCUPATION_WORK_FULLTIME,
                    User::OCCUPATION_WORK_PARTTIME => User::OCCUPATION_WORK_PARTTIME,
                    User::OCCUPATION_NATIONAL_SERVICE => User::OCCUPATION_NATIONAL_SERVICE,
                    User::OCCUPATION_UNEMPLOYED => User::OCCUPATION_UNEMPLOYED,
                    User::OCCUPATION_OTHERS => User::OCCUPATION_OTHERS,
                ),
                'choices_as_values' => true,
            )
        );
```

...
}

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, if that answer your question, but since PHP 5.6 (i hope this is the right version) u can create constancs as an arrays:

```
const OCCUPATION = [
        User::OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_HIGHER_DEGREE,
        User::OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_LOWER_DEGREE,
        ....
    ];
```

or

```
    const OCCUPATION = [
            OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_HIGHER_DEGREE => 'Schülerin/Schüler an Gymnasium',
            OCCUPATION_WORK_TRAINING => 'Berufsausbildung',
            ....
        ];
```

Now u can access directly in you form:

```
     'choices' => User::OCCUPATION
```

Or u can write u a getter $user->getOccupation();

Comment: Thanks Snirgel. I thought that was only available in PHP 7. The problem in my case is that the Choice Assert expects a simple array http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#choices (I think) and in your example "OCCUPATION_SCHOOL_HIGHER_DEGREE" would be stored in the DB and not the actual value.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DictionaryBundle) few month ago and I think it could match with your need.

You store the possible values in your `config.yml` (you can use your class constants). Then you can use the dedicated form type to retrieve your choices and add a validation constraint in your entity.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I have a look at how they have done it. I don' really want to install a bundle for this but maybe I they have used I good solution that I can implement. I am more curious at how this should be done.